# vb.net syntax error in UPDATE statement. Code attached

Tags: database, vb.net

Hi I am trying to UPDATE an access database with VB.net and am getting a Syntax Error. Everything else in my program works except this!

## Error:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException was unhandled ErrorCode=-2147217900
>   HResult=-2147217900 Message=Syntax error in UPDATE statement.
>   Source=Microsoft Office Access Database Engine StackTrace:    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult
>   hr)    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS
>   dbParams, Object& executeResult)    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object&
>   executeResult)    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, Object& executeResult)    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method)    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()    at
>   WindowsApplication3.Form2.AddAddButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs
>   e) in C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\WindowsApplication3\WindowsApplication3\Form2.vb:line 83
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons
>   button, Int32 clicks)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
>   m)    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr
>   hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>   at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr
>   dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(ApplicationContext context)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[]
>   commandLine)    at WindowsApplication3.My.MyApplication.Main(String[]
>   Args) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 81    at
>   System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[]
>   args)    at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart() InnerException:

## Code:

```
Private Sub AddAddButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddAddButton.Click

    Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\*****************************;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=*********;")
    Dim insertsql As String
    Try
        insertsql = "UPDATE RepairOrders SET ROOther = @Other,  ROJobType = @Type, SET ROJobTime = @Time, SET RODelPicDate = @DelPic WHERE RONo = @JobNo"
        Dim cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(insertsql, conn)

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Other", AddOtherText.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", AddTypeCombo.SelectedValue)
        If AddTimeCombo.Text = "AM" Then
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time", Convert.ToInt32("1"))
        Else
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time", Convert.ToInt32("2"))
        End If
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time", Convert.ToInt32(AddTimeCombo.SelectedValue))
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DelPic", AddDatePick.Value.Date.ToString)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JobNo", Convert.ToInt32(AddJobText.Text))

        conn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("Booking Added!")
        conn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

I have hidden some sensitive information in the code. Please help me identify this issue. Thankyou :)

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple `SET` in your query. Change it to

```
insertsql = "UPDATE RepairOrders SET ROOther = @Other,  
ROJobType = @Type, ROJobTime = @Time, RODelPicDate = @DelPic WHERE RONo = @JobNo"
```

Comment: I have added updated code to the OP. I am now getting the error " Cannot Update 'ROOther'; field not updateable.

Comment: @user3457511: Is your Access column marked as ReadOnly? I found this: http://database.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/access-l/field-not-updatable-36768

Comment: @user3457511 That's a separate problem and the error message is rather helpful in this case. If you still cannot resolve it, you should ask a separate question.